# cakephp returns error on empty array?

Tags: arrays, cakephp

I am doing a simple find to select a opponent for a game:

```
return $this->find('first'....
```

As long as I find a player, the function returns the array of results...
But as soon as I get no results, the array is empty, I get the following error message:

```
Warning (2): strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\Cake\Network\CakeResponse.php, line 496]

Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\Cake\Network\CakeResponse.php, line 525]

Array
```

I can't really understand why I get this error and where it is based.
Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot blindly use the returned result array afterwards.
Check if !empty() and only proceed to use its content if there is actually something to use in there.

Comment: Or you can check with `$this->hasAny($conditions)` or `$this->exists()` if you have an id to see if the record exists first, and then do your logic accordingly.

Comment: Found the problem, was based in the way I return the data. Forgot to set the $this->response->body right in order to return the data as json. Sorry, sometimes I have to write down a problem in order to see the error :-)